# What's the simplest way to copy an item from a DynamoDB stream to another table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have two dynamoDB tables, table1 and table2, with a stream enabled on table1. Both have a string key called "id". I also have a lambda function that reads inserts to table1 from the stream and mirrors them to table2 if they meet certain criteria. Here's my JS code (ES6 syntax) that doesn't quite work:

```
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function mirrorInserts(event, context, callback) {
  event.Records.forEach((record) => {
    if (record.eventName != 'INSERT') {
      console.log('Ignored ' + record.eventName + ' stream event.');
      return;
    }

    var input = record.dynamodb.NewImage;
    var id = input.id.S
    if (myCondition(input)( {
        const params = {
            TableName: table2,
            Key: {
              id: id,
            },
            Item: input,
         };
         dynamoDb.put(createParams, (result, error) => {
             if (error) {
                 console.error(error);
             }
         });
      });            
    }
```

Using this function gives this error:

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key id
>   expected: S actual: M

The message is easy enough to interpret, but I'm confused by it since the id that I'm using should be a string. Additionally, is there an easy way to just insert the whole item, as-is?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the AWS document client expects standard JSON objects, not the annotated AttributeValues that come directly out of the DB. I used [dynamodb-data-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-data-types) to unwrap the data and everything worked. Specifically, I added

```
const attr = require('dynamodb-data-types').AttributeValue;
```

and then changed the params to

```
const params = {
    TableName: table2,
    Key: {
      id: id,
    },
    Item: attr.unwrap(input),
 };
```